# httpd(2.4.25), openssl(1.0.2k) - Cannot compile in macOS Sierra Error on make: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_CRYPTO_malloc_init"

Tags: macos, apache

Operating system is macOS Sierra, osx 10.12.3

Configure command line:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/apache-2.4.25 --enable-so --enable-ssl  --with-ssl=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.0.2k --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr-util
```

Error created by make:

```
/usr/local/apr-1.5.2/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 
-L/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.0.2k/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread  \
             -o ab  ab.lo       /usr/local/apr-util-1.5.4/lib/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat -liconv /usr/local/apr-1.5.2/lib/libapr-1.la -lpthread  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_CRYPTO_malloc_init", referenced from:
      _main in ab.o   "_OPENSSL_init_ssl", referenced from:
      _main in ab.o   "_OPENSSL_sk_num", referenced from:
      _ssl_proceed_handshake in ab.o   "_OPENSSL_sk_value", referenced from:
      _ssl_proceed_handshake in ab.o   "_SSL_CTX_set_options", referenced from:
      _main in ab.o   "_SSL_in_init", referenced from:
      _main in ab.o
      _ssl_state_cb in ab.o   "_TLS_client_method", referenced from:
      _main in ab.o   "_X509_get_version", referenced from:
      _ssl_print_cert_info in ab.o   "_X509_getm_notAfter", referenced from:
      _ssl_print_cert_info in ab.o   "_X509_getm_notBefore", referenced from:
      _ssl_print_cert_info in ab.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/server/apache.html

From there I found two dependencies [Apr-Util-1.5.4](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/apr-util.html) and [PCRE-8.40](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre.html).

I configure the build of apr-util with:

```
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/apr-util-1.5.4 --with-apr=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/apr-1.5.2 --with-openssl=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.0.2k --with-crypto
```

Most important was to build apr-util with --with-openssl=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.0.2k --with-crypto.

I then built pcre-8.40 as I had been attempting to build with pcre-8.39.

I believe the root cause was not building with apr-util-1.5.4 with the --with-openssl=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.0.2k --with-crypto options.

My configuration before make for apache-2.4.25 was:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/apache-2.4.25 --enable-so --enable-ssl  --with-ssl=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.0.2k --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/apr-util-1.5.4 --with-ldap
```